# WPF ListBox fixed width

Tags: wpf, listbox, width, fixed

I have a `ListBox` in a `PopupControl`. Problem is that while scrolling, Popup resizes
to fit the actual widest element.

How can I avoid this resizing and adjust automatically to the widest element in the whole list?

I tried to put it in a `Grid` but without success.

Comment: Are you able to calculate how wide a particular ListBoxItem will be, based on its content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep virtualizing on, you can set the `Popup.Width` to a constant.

Of course, to pick the right constant, you'll have to calculate (or at least guess) how wide each `ListBoxItem` will be, and pick the max. ... Usually it's not too hard to get a rough guess, based on your content.

Answer (score 8):

ok this is the solution: Adding this property

```
<ListBox VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
```

The resizing stops because now the Panel contains all elements and the width is adjusted
respecting the widest one.
With Virtualizing Panel, it's only a part of items displayed and the ListBox adjusts the widht to the actual visible widest element.

Disadvantade is, that we do not use **Virtualizing Panel** anymore (which is default on)

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the exact same problem as described above - my ListBox would NOT virtualize because it would be busy layouting inside a resizable PopUp control. The solution I have found is to limit the `MaxWidth` and `MaxHeight` of the Grid that contains the `ListBox`. My `PopUp` control is still resizable with a Grip - its just not unlimited in the space it can take up - I think thats quit an easy solution to implement once it is known this can fix the problem :-)

I know the `ListBox` is virtualizing because a query with about 18,000 elements is answered in 1-2 seconds instead of 30-60 seconds and scrolling is quick instead of frozen.

```
<Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"
       AllowsTransparency="true"  
       PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_ContentHost}"                                   
       Placement="Bottom"                                                        
       IsOpen="{Binding IsPopupOpened, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"                                     
       PopupAnimation="None"
       Focusable="False"
       StaysOpen="True"
    >
    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding PopupBorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding PopupBorderThickness}"
            Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static reskeys:ResourceKeys.ControlPopupBackgroundBrushKey}}"  
            >
        <!-- Do NOT REMOVE MaxHeight and MaxWidth
             These ensure that containing ListBox is virtualizing -->
        <Grid x:Name="PART_ResizeableGrid" Background="Transparent"
              MaxHeight="600"
              MaxWidth="600"
              >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Border
                x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"  
                Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=PART_ContentHost}"                                             
                Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=PART_ContentHost}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                BorderThickness="0"
                />

            <ListBox
                x:Name="PART_ItemList" Grid.Row="0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Suggestions, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                BorderThickness="0"
                ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"                                                             
                Template="{DynamicResource {x:Static reskeys:ResourceKeys.PopListBoxControlTemplate}}"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"

                DisplayMemberPath="{TemplateBinding DisplayMemberPath}"
                SelectedValuePath="{TemplateBinding ValuePath}"

                KeyboardNavigation.AcceptsReturn="True"
                KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"

                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
                />

            <!-- RezizeGrip Thumb to support resizing the suggestion lib -->
            <Thumb x:Name="PART_ResizeGripThumb"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static reskeys:ResourceKeys.ResizeGripStyleKey}}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                   Margin="0"
                   Background="Transparent"
                   Width="16"
                   Height="16" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

Answer (score -1):

Most WPF `UIElement` controls have a `Width` property which can be set to "`Auto`" so they will take up as much space as their widest element.

Comment: I don't think that works in this case, as nothing has determined what the widest element is if virtualizing is turned on.